How do I programmatically reset manifest settings as RequiredModules
The Update-ModuleManifest lets you programmatically update settings, but how do I programmatically reset a setting as RequiredModules back to its original setting ("no required modules"):
# RequiredModules = @() 

Tried:
Update-ModuleManifest .\Test\Test.psd1 -RequiredModules @()


Update-ModuleManifest: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'RequiredModules'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the command again.

Update-ModuleManifest .\Test\Test.psd1 -RequiredModules '' 


Update-ModuleManifest: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'RequiredModules'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the command again.

Update-ModuleManifest .\Test\Test.psd1 -RequiredModules $Null


Update-ModuleManifest: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'RequiredModules'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.


This looks like an oversight in the parameter design. I'd suggest opening an issue on GitHub to add [AllowEmptyCollection()] to the relevant parameter definitions

Scratch that, I submitted an issue here

It appears that the new PSResourceGet module contains a newer version of the Update-ModuleManifest cmdlet with a slightly different name Update-PSModuleManifest (1.0.6).
This version works as expected:
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerShell.PSResourceGet -RequiredVersion 1.0.6
Update-PSModuleManifest -Path .\Tests.psd1 -NestedModules @()

